# Which Protractor version supports Angular 8?

Tags: protractor, angular8

We already have protractor e2e tests for angular 7. Now the app is getting upgraded to angular 8. Does protractor 5.4.2 support angular 8? We are using chrome browser.

Comment: maybe try this https://www.google.com/search?q=protractor+compatibility+angular&oq=protractor+compatibility+angular&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.17756j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor framework can find, interact etc. within sites that were implemented by Angular, Vue, React, js/html...

Protractor has just few Angular specific methods. It is:

- `waitForAngular(false/true)`: I suggest to make it `false` in `onPrepare()` block inside configuration protractor file. The reason of it that it was implemented for Angular 1. On current versions it works pretty unstable;
- angular specific selectors. `css` or `xpath` quite enough for searching elements.